Why do I have to explicitly alias columns in spring-data-jpa projections?
I am trying to use interface based projections in my spring-data-jpa repositories. I am stuck on trying to understand this behaviour.
Suppose my database table is:
trueAge | weight | firstName
25      | 25.00  | "blah"

My JPA entity is:
@Entity
class X {
...
trueAge: int, // notice the names match exactly
weight: double, // I am not naming my columns differently
firstName: String 
...
}

Hence, my interface:
interface MyProjection {
fun getTrueAge(): int,
fun getWeight(): double,
fun getFirstName(): String
}

Using a repository like so:
@Query("SELECT trueAge, weight, firstName FROM X WHERE id = 42") // notice the absence of column aliases
fun gimmeSomething(): MyProjection

This leads to an NPE at runtime.

I can get past this by explicitly aliasing the columns like so:
@Query("SELECT trueAge as trueAge, weight as weight, firstName as firstName FROM X WHERE id = 42") // even though the alias has the same name as the db column
fun gimmeSomething(): MyProjection

Questions:

Why is this needed even when the names are same?
Should the method names in the interface match the name of the column alias or the property in the entity POJO ?
Where is this documented ?

